# Running Python Script consistently from VBA

Tags: python, vba, oracle, shell, sqlalchemy

I have VBA code calling a Python script that works on my PC.

The Python code uses SQL Alchemy to create an Engine, connects to a database, binds the session and retrieve data using a `SELECT * FROM` basic query. After it reads it, the data is sent to an xlsx file.

Python code with some minor changes for security reasons:

```py
# import dependencies
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
import pandas as pd
import os
import cx_Oracle

# Creating engine connection
engine = create_engine('oracle://user:pw@IP:Port/Schema')
# Binding session
session = Session(bind=engine)
# Indicating path for Oracle client 64bits
lib_dir = r"Full_Path\instantclient_19_9"
try:
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=lib_dir)
except Exception as err:
    print("Error connecting: cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client()")
    print(err);
    sys.exit(1);

# read sql a run query
data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM Schema.V_FLUJOS_SOLICITADOS", engine)
# save path 
path = r'Another_Full_Path'
# save dataframe into csv
data.to_excel(os.path.join(path, r'Flow extraction.xlsx'), index = False)
```

For this code, I need to tell Python where to find the Oracle client of 64 bits because my company has its database connected to a PowerBuilder program that can only use 32 bit, so I just can't change the installation, that's why I re-route.

VBA code:

```vb
Sub runScript()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
teoricos = ThisWorkbook.Name
Dim Ret_Val
user = Environ("UserName")

Select Case user
    Case "USER1"
    python_route = "C:\Users\USER1\Anaconda3\python.exe"
    Case "USER2"
    python_route = "C:\Users\USER2\Anaconda3\python.exe"
End Select

args = """Full_path\V_FLUJOS_SOLICITADOS.py"""
Ret_Val = Shell(python_route & " " & args, vbNormalFocus)
If Ret_Val = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Couldn't run python script!", vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

The code works on my PC (User 1), but it doesn't on my partner's PC.

What I've done so far:

- Installed cx_Oracle on her machine
- Tested the whole code on Jupyter Notebook of her machine and it worked
- Tested full access to all paths
- Activated the Microsoft Shell Reference in VBA

The VBA code on her PC runs, but it just opens the command window really fast and it closes.
On my PC it takes from 3 to 5 seconds to do the whole thing, so I can see the CMD for just a bit there (and also check that the file updated which is the most clear indicator that it worked).

Comment: as a suggestion, you can write some log after each line to a .txt to check where the execution stops. After that you can try some `Try/catch` or `On error:` to catch the exception or leave the console opened in case something is logged

Comment: I would agree with adding some verbose logging. I have had similar issues even with my own code running ok initially, then not. I put it down to IT switching off certain command line interactions but never had confirmation. Is it the computer or the login? Can you run it fine on her machine under your profile?

Comment: I will try today the logs of each step, thank you for the idea. @QHarr I can't login with my user on her PC, everyone has an untransferable user.